# relevance of table tags in html page layout

Tags: html

I'm a newbie here and I have a question which has been bothering my mind. In html, is the table tag: `<table></table>` still useful for making page layout nowadays? Also, do i still need to have a basic knowledge of it, because the `<div>` tag and `<span>` tag have become a good part of me when I lay out my web pages.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a matter of using tables or divs/spans for layout. You don't use either for layout.

HTML elements are used to describe structure and semantics (and there is plenty of data out there with a structure best expressed using a table).

CSS is used for layout.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to layout a web page. Although the `<table>` tag is one option that was quite popular, it is no longer considered the best practice. It is still used often and it is useful to have an understanding of how it functions.

I recommend that if you are new to web design and best practices that you take some time and explore the W3School's website. It is full of tutorials and interactive examples that are incredibly useful and informative.

There site is: https://www.w3schools.com/

For their explanation on the `<table>` tag and its uses see:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Here is  their article on website layout:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: "explore the W3School's website" — No, don't. It's awful. Lots of out of date practises and code demos with security holes.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed, and I am not trying implying that it is perfect. However, it is a good place for someone to start. Especially regarding HTML & CSS

Comment: It's a terrible place to start. It shows the worst way to approach most problems.

Comment: @Quentin It appears we are arguing over a matter of opinion that is not relevant to the question at hand. I feel that this is not the best place for a discussion of the overall usefulness of W3S. If you have some other recommendations, please share them. They will no doubt be of use to the OP and others in the community.